# Designing specific functions

Tags: javascript, html, css

I need know if I can design a HTML page with conflict of functions, for example I have  3 css that can't be together in the same because I get a big mistake; I need know if I can put together those CSS under hierarchy, therefore where is one CSS the other CSS wont can... is like put limits to an CSS, the same I want do with some Scripts.

This is an example of code which I'm thinking to do.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"/>
  
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css"> <!-- MAIN or GENERAL CSS -->
  
</head>

<body class='landing-page  wsite-theme-light'>

<div> Where CSS 1 IS 
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style01.css">
<div/>

<div> Where CSS 2 IS 
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style02.css">
<div/>

<div> Where CSS 3 IS 
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style03.css">
<div/>


  <div class="nav mobile-nav">{menu}</div>

  <script type="text/javascript" src="/files/theme/plugins01.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/files/theme/custom01.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

The main problem is those CSS have something which I don't need, and something which I need, I can't understand where is what I need.

Comment: This is what CSS classes are for. You can include a single, or multiple, stylesheets, each with a variety of styles, and by using classes or other selectors you can choose which styles should be applied to what elements.

Comment: Do you want to restrict css files to enable each only in own part of page?

Comment: *"I can't understand where is what I need."*: if you don't know which parts of your CSS you need, how could we? This question will have more success if you turn it into a *clear* question.

Comment: @Julia Yes... is this possible?

Comment: Thanks @Jake , I will take this in account.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's not how CSS works. The `<link rel="stylesheet" ...>` tags go in the head of the HTML, which means you can't have a specific CSS for different parts of the page.

You use classes, and identifiers to make your CSS code specific to a section. You can try this:

```
<div id="style1"> Where CSS 1 IS 
...
<div/>

<div id="style2"> Where CSS 2 IS 
...
<div/>

<div id="style3"> Where CSS 3 IS 
...
<div/>
```

And in your CSS, you can specialize styles for different DIVs using the following code:

```
#style1 { 
    background-color: yellow;
}
#style2 { 
    background-color: black;
}
#style3 { 
    background-color: orange;
}
```